# Git checkout a commit and attach to existing branch

Tags: git, commit, head

I have a local repo and I want to fast-forward it to a specific commit (which may not be the HEAD of the remote repo).

So I do:

```
git fetch master
git checkout sha
```

This however puts me in a detached HEAD state, which I don't want. Is there an equivalent to `git checkout -b branch_name sha`, which works when branch_name already exist?

In short, I have to update the HEAD of my local repo to a remote commit. I already tried `git pull origin sha` with no success. I cannot use `git pull origin master` because that will fast-forward to the HEAD of the remote, while I want to fast-forward to a specific commit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to merge up to a specific commit, fetch all remote changes and specify this commit's id:

```
git fetch origin
git merge <sha1 of commit you want to merge>
```

You can specify the `--ff-only` option and have Git fail when it cannot fast-forward (and would create a new merge commit).

---

If you only want to put a single commit on top of your current branch's tip, use cherry-pick (but this is usually not recommended):

```
git cherry-pick <sha1 of commit you want to merge>
```

Comment: I don't know why but when I use `git pull` it does not work: `fatal: Couldn't find remote ref 2dcdc60153ed38b1cd971aa91d1ea9b42b5c29c7
Unexpected end of command stream`. However `git merge` does, so I'll use that.

Comment: One question: in this particular local repo I never commit and never change the files, so I think it will always be able to fast forward right?

Comment: Fast-forwarding does not happen on a file level, but on a commit level. If you create local commits you cannot fast-forward (even if they don't touch that file). And yeah, you are right about pull – it will only allow to pull named refs.

Comment: Ok, so since in that local repo I never commit I should always be able to fast forward.

Comment: @rubik: Yes, _unless_ your remote side forces a non-fast-forward push (e.g. reset, rebase, commit --amend). Not recommended for published history, but you'll never know …

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

checkout master

checkout your sha

then crate branch from the existing sha1

```
git checkout -f masetr
git checkout SHA1
git checkout -b 'BRANCH_NAME'
```